# Unidentified Component in an AC motor speed drive unit

Tags: induction-motor, motor-controller

I opened by curiosity an AC single phase motor speed driver unit to understand how it works, however, i found an unknown component that i don't know what it is.

Its the first time i see this kind of component. It looks like a 9 pins black box without any reference on it and it is inserted in the PCB with a label Ouf1 engraved on the silk.

[image: S]

1,2 : Input of variable resistors switch

3,4:  Output to the AC Motor

5,6:  230 VAC Power Input

The variable resistors that control the motor speed and the power MOSFET all of them converge to this black box:

[image]

Any one have an idea what it could be ?

**UPDATE:**

I removed it from the PCB, here is how it looks from bottom, it seems there is another mini PCB inside.

[image]

Comment: Me-thinks that the manufacturer does not want to tell you what's in their speed/current controller.

Comment: A potted hybrid? Crack it open and find out what's inside like a good engineer!

Comment: @JackCreasey  yes, maybe

Comment: @winny i removed it from the PCB and updated my post, however, it is difficult to uncover the hidden circuit from the black box without breaking it because it is glued inside

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's not a standard component.
It just a (custom) sub-circuit probably in [thick-film hybrid technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_integrated_circuit) or just on a small PCB potted with resin inside a plastic box.

One reason to do this might be

- to make it more difficult to reverse engineer (what Jack Creasey noted) but there are also other reasons, e.g.
- to make crtitical parts mechanically or chemically more robust,
- to have better thermal coupling,
- to produce the subcircuit common in various designs in higher quantity and only vary a few external components for each versions etc.

Comment: I updated my post with the black box removed from PCB, there is a printed circuit inside glued to the black box, you think its a protection from the manufacturer against reverse engineering or a mechanical protection ? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a "Thick Film" unit to me. Used a lot on customized controllers. Easier to make than an IC chip when doing low volumes of proprietary circuitry. And yes, you will not be able to reverse engineer it unless you are REALLY good... that's a secondary purpose to using them instead of putting all of the components on a board.